# Including the includePath property of a separate root in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include-path

Is it possible to reference the `includePath` property of another root's `c_cpp_properties.json` in a multi-root project?

For example, if I have roots `Main` and `Secondary` in a multi-root project, where `Secondary`'s `c_cpp_properties.json` looks something like:

```
...
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/Include",
    "${workspaceFolder}/Subdir1/Include"
    "${workspaceFolder}/Subdir2/Include"
]
...
```

and I also want those include paths in the `Main` root. Currently, the best I have is something like the following in `Main`'s `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
...
"includePath": [
    ...
    "${workspaceFolder:Secondary}/Include",
    "${workspaceFolder:Secondary}/Subdir1/Include",
    "${workspaceFolder:Secondary}/Subdir2/Include",
    ...
]
...
```

but this isn't ideal if `Secondary` has a large number of include paths and `Main` wants to use the include paths of many other roots, not to mention it being (hopefully unnecessary) duplication.

I guess I'm looking for something along the lines of `"${workspaceFolder:Secondary:includePath}"` to add to `Main`. Is there anything like this available?

Comment: The best approach is to let your build system configure the paths, which one are you using?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Agreed, but because of the nature of the project `compile_commands.json` is in-feasibly large - in the hundreds of megabytes - and causes performance issues on VS Code.